# Adding Rich Text to an AcroField in iTextSharp

Tags: .net, pdf-generation, itext

I need to add some formatted text to a PDF form field using iTextSharp and I can't seem to figure it out. This is how I'm currently setting the fields, but certain portions of the inserted text will need to be bold or have other formatting.

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetField("fieldName", "fieldValue")
stamper.FormFlattening = True
```

I've seen [elsewhere](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg32137.html) that I should be able to insert some xml that includes formatting information instead, but I have no idea what this xml should look like.

Here's the section from that page that leads me to believe that what I want is possible:

> It still stamps the actual XML code
>   onto the field and the Reader will not
>   render it as rich text in the stamped
>   PDF.

And the working response to this:

> For that to work you'll have to call
>   AcroFields.setGenerateAppearances(false).
>   Note that older Reader versions don't
>   generate appearances.

What should this xml look like, or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while back, I added the ability to iText to set the rich text value of a field.  I didn't add any rendering code to back this up.

That means the only way to see that rich value is via a PDF viewer that supports it (Reader/Acrobat).  In order for them to know they need to rebuild all field appearances, you have to call `acroFields.setGenerateAppearances(false)`.  This disables iText's appearance generation, and instead requests that the PDF viewer do it for you.

If you want *flattened rich text* wholly within iText[Sharp] you're going to have to do something screwy:

1. Draw your rich text into a PDF page in a separate document.  The size of this page should match the size of the field.  Save it out (a memory stream is fine).
2. Add a new `PushbuttonField`, set to `LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY`.  Use the same bounding box as the original text field.  Set the pushbutton's background color to `null` (transparent).
3. Create a `PdfImportedPage` of your rich-text page and set this imported page to be the new `PushbuttonField`'s icon (template).
4. Flatten.

Painful, but effective.

You can do #1 with HTMLWorker and use your original rich text/HTML as input.

In fact, you could probably get quite a bit more efficient with an HTMLWorker feeding a ColumnText object to render your HTML in the same document rather than a new one, then write it out and read it back in again.  Whip up a PdfTemplate from any old page's DirectContent with the appropriate bounding box.

That would suck much less.

Comment: I'm accepting this with the hope that it is a valid answer, but I haven't even looked at any relevant code in a long time and can't test this. If someone else sees this and could verify the answer, that would be great!

Comment: I tried to use this approach with no success. The temp document is empty. Code can be found at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397431/underline-form-field-value-using-itextsharp